# json data fetched from php and store them in an array in java

Tags: java, php, arrays, json

My JSON array is this:

```
{"Name_1":1,"Name_2":0,"Name_3":0}
```

and my code in java for getting the values and store them in a separate array is the following:

```
int[] operations= new int[3];
             String result = "";
             InputStream is = null;
             StringBuilder sb=null;
                try{
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://testteamgr.netau.net/parsing/test.php");
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
            }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }
            //convert response to string
            try{
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();

                    result=sb.toString();
            }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }
            try{

                JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                System.out.println("Length of json is"+jArray.length());
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                       if (i==0) operations[0]=json_data.getInt("Name_1");
                       else if (i==1) operations[1]=json_data.getInt("Name_2");
                       else if (i==2) operations[2]=json_data.getInt("Name_3"); }
```

and I am getting those errors:

> value br of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonobject

If I print out the result I do not see the JSONobject but the html code.

So what I want is to get these 3 values into a separate array.

Comment: I think it's because you ask an array whereas you just got a object. In JSON, arrays are wrapped wetween [ and ], you've got { and }, that means an object.

Comment: code edited but problem remains

Comment: which Log gives you this error?

Comment: code is the above. If I add a println of the result, after result=sb.toString I see html being printed out.

Answer (score 1):

You have an object, not an array. To process the result you can use following code:

```
    String json = "{\"Name_1\":1,\"Name_2\":0,\"Name_3\":0}";
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
    String[] propertyNames = JSONObject.getNames(object);
    String[] values = new String[propertyNames.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.length; i++) {
        values[i] = String.valueOf(object.get(propertyNames[i]));
    }
```

Comment: what if the String json is not static? As you can see is code that I fetch from a php script.

Comment: I used that just for example, try to use your fetched value instead, it should work.